# event.touches detecting multiple touch events after touch screen spam

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, d3.js

I am building a web application for an exhibition where we are using a touch screen as interaction input. If a user decides to spam the screen (like crazy), event.touches will after a while believe that one touch (one finger) contains several touch events. Even if i refresh the web page (f5 / shift-f5 yields the same results), it will still tell me that a one finger touch is a touch in several different locations. The only way to completely reset it seems to be a complete restart of the browser.

The web app is constructed for Chrome.

Does anybody know what causes this, and how to prevent it? I have tried putting a 100% screen-size overlay with pointer-events:none if the touch points exceed 5 (to prevent more touches), but even so Chrome registers the touches and goes bananas.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The bug does not appear in the Metro/Windows 8 mode for Chrome. However, Metro Chrome does not respect --kiosk, which makes it unusable in the exhibition.

Comment: just a shot in the dark really but have you tried running d3.timer.flush()? It sounds like maybe the feature that owns the touch behaviour is being re-initialised but the previous instances are not GCed because there are callbacks from timers that were set by those instances. You can get that in force layouts for example.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as soon as I can. However, shouldn't all d3 events/timers/calls/etc reset upon refresh?

Comment: It is desirable but the timer queue is super light because it's hot code but sometimes it's a little too light maybe.  There is an [open issue on this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2468) that will be fixed in a future release.  More detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1790)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. Thank you anyways. :)

Comment: Yes, OK, like I said: shot in the dark.  Can you post some code or provide a link to the working site?

Comment: We solved it. Updated to Windows 10, and that change (either windows or chrome update) removed the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Windows 10 solved the issue.